# MYSQL - Upsert from one table to another

Tags: mysql, upsert

I am trying to use upsert to update and or insert from another table

```
INSERT INTO table1 (
  `uniqueCol1`, 
  `uniqueCol2`, 
  `created`, 
  `dataCol`
) 
VALUES (
   1, 
   t1.uniqueCol2Value, 
   NOW(), 
   t1.dataColValue 
) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   `dataCol` = t1.dataColValue
```

Now from what I can tell I don't see how I can add what I think should be `FROM table2 t1` into this to grab the values and put them into table1

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (
  `uniqueCol1`, 
  `uniqueCol2`, 
  `created`, 
  `dataCol`
) 
SELECT 1, uniqueCol2Value, NOW(), dataColValue FROM table2
```